# Fullscreen jQuery fadein/out animations stutter in webkitbased browsers (Chrome/Safari)

Tags: jquery, webkit, fadein

I have a few (almost)fullscreen fadeIn/Out animations on my website which are stuttering in Safari and Chrome (Windows 7 64bit, jQuery 1.7.2):
(http://portfolio.wezelkrozum.nl/#page=news&par1=article&par2=1&par3=)

The animations appear when you click on an thumbnail. I would love to know if there's a smoother way to implement these animations. So far I've changed the script so the images  become visable after the fade in animation is completed. It made the animation more smooth but not smooth enough.

So, how could I improve the fading animations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [2D Transformations](https://github.com/heygrady/transform) plugin.
No need to edit anything, just include .js in . It will use css transitions in jQuery animation calls when possible.

I opened your site in Chrome (OS X) & Safari (OS X), animations seem fine.

EDIT:

1) add style `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` to `wrapper`  (wraps thumbnails) and to `article_images_manager` . It activates GPU acceleration in Webkit. :-)

2) you should not use full images as thumbnails, but pregenerated small ones.

Comment: I added the plugin but sadly enough couldn't see any performance boost. I'm using jQuery 1.7.2, maybe it's already using css3 transitions?

Comment: (Couldn't edit my comment, so: ) I'm using Windows 7 but it should'nt make a difference. The animation stutter only applies to the imageviewer.

Comment: Opened your web on Windows/Firefox and Windows/Chrome - supersmooth fade transitions both on FF&Chrome on over the 2 years old desktop with superold GPU card, no issues there. // OT: add html { overflow-y: scroll } to your css to permanently show scrollbar ;-)

Comment: Babca, I don't want to show the scrollbar when the imageviewer is on top ;)
I tried Chrome and Safari on serveral pc's and these are the results:
Chrome on a low-end PC: No fade animations (1 frame) at all in the imageviewer.
Chrome on a mid-end laptop: Stuttering (2/3 frames) fade animation when opening or closing the imageviewer. No fade animation when navigating through the images.
Safari on a mid-end laptop: Stuttering fade animations. (4/5 frames when opening the imageviewer, 2 frames when navigating through the images)
Safari/Chrome on high-end pc: Stuttering (~7 frames) animations

Comment: I decided to use the slideUp animation instead. For now the animation is good enough.

Comment: Oh sorry, I haven't noticed the gallery page, only article thumbnails, I thought you mean that. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: 2) I know, these were just thumbnails for test purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the problem. You may want to try the css3 transitions rather than jQuery animate. They will definitely increase the performance.